# ClassNotFound exception when mocking static classes with PowerMockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I have a project by name `Utility` and it has a class by name `Util` as below:

```
public class Util {
    public static String verify() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("Endpoint");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
        // Parsing the response as String
        String resp = .......
        return resp;
    }
}
```

I have another project by name `Consumer` and it has a class by name `Service` as below:

```
public class Service {
    public String verify() {
        String resp = Util.verify();
        return resp;
    }
}
```

I have added `Utility` as a dependency for `Consumer` as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>utility</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have a unit test case for the `Service` class where I am mocking the `Util` class with `PowerMockito` as:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Util.class })
public class ServiceTest {
    Service service = new Service();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Util.verify()).thenReturn("mockedResponse");
    }

    @Test
    public void testVerify() {
        String resp = service.verify();
        assertEquals(resp, "mockedResponse");
    }
}
```

This test throws NotFoundException for ProtocolSocketFactory. Does anyone know why I see this exception? I am trying to mock the `Util` class, but PowerMockito tries to initialize the class before mocking it. If I add `HttpClient` as a dependency in `pom.xml` for project `Consumer`, then the error goes away and the mocking is successful.

The Powermockito version I am using is 1.6.2

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.my.company.Util. Reason: cannot find org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: cannot find org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:215)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:418)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:212)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1431)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:74)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:251)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.toCtClass(Descriptor.java:592)
    at javassist.bytecode.Descriptor.getParameterTypes(Descriptor.java:439)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:188)
    ... 61 more
```